Customized subplots in the diagonal in the sns.PairGrid
I am trying to add a line to match the data in vars with different "source". The codes below got "KeyError: None"
df_combined.columns
Index(['Temp (°C)', 'RH (%)', 'CO2 (ppm)', 'PM2.5 (µg/m³)', 'SH (g/kg)',
   'Source']

The df_combined looks like:



TimeSeries
Temp (°C)
RH (%)
PM2.5 (µg/m³)
SH (g/kg)
Source




2024-03-01 00:00:00
19.556857
52.384013
474.000000
0.794159
BF


2024-03-01 00:15:00
19.792490
50.691260
473.931034
0.714120
BF


2024-03-01 00:30:00
19.877775
49.918059
471.533333
0.676270
BF


2024-03-01 00:45:00
19.855077
49.405916
469.700000
0.705883
BF


2024-03-01 01:00:00
19.719011
48.791986
467.965517
0.713488
BF


2024-03-01 00:00:00
19.556857
52.384013
474.000000
0.794159
ATF


2024-03-01 00:15:00
19.792490
50.691260
473.931034
0.714120
ATF


2024-03-01 00:30:00
19.877775
49.918059
471.533333
0.676270
ATF


2024-03-01 00:45:00
19.855077
49.405916
469.700000
0.705883
ATF


2024-03-01 01:00:00
19.719011
48.791986
467.965517
0.713488
ATF



The codes is as followed:
g = sns.PairGrid(
    data=df_combined,
    vars=['Temp (°C)', 'SH (g/kg)', 'CO2 (ppm)', 'PM2.5 (µg/m³)'],
    hue="Source",
    height=2.5, aspect=1.5,
    diag_sharey=False, despine=False
)

# Map histograms and additional line plots to the diagonal
def diagonal_with_line(xdata, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()  # Get the current axis
    variable = kwargs.get('var')  # Extract the variable name
    hue = kwargs.get('hue')  # Extract the hue parameter if available
    # Plot the histogram
    sns.histplot(x=xdata, kde=False, **kwargs, ax=ax)

    ax2 = ax.twinx()

    # Add a line plot for each hue value separately
    # Add a line plot (example: normal fit)
    # Compute a fitted normal distribution PDF as an example
    for level in xdata[hue].unique():
        subset = xdata[xdata[hue] == level]
        mu, std = np.mean(subset), np.std(subset)
        x_vals = np.linspace(stats.norm.ppf(0.01, scale=std, loc=mu),
                             stats.norm.ppf(0.99, scale=std, loc=mu), 1000)
        pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x=x_vals, scale=std, loc=mu)
        ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=x_vals, y=pdf, color='red', label="normal fit", ax=ax2)


# Replace the diagonal mapping with the custom function
g.map_diag(diagonal_with_line)

# Map scatter plots to the off-diagonal plots
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)

If I remove the for loop, I can get the figure below.
without loop

Please provide a [mre], i.e. minimal code that is sufficient to reproduce your issue. You're not providing a dummy dataset here. We should be able to copy/paste your code and get the same graph.

On what line is the error? maybe one of your variable is empty.

I think the issue is caused by the "for level in xdata[hue].unique():"

@mozway I added a pic with the df. It is very simple I think. Thank you.

@rehaqds I think the code "hue = kwargs.get('hue')" can be used to get the "hue". But I am not sure how to use it in the following codes to call "hue" and use it to process the data in the personal func.

A picture is note reproducible: How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Why don't you print a few rows of your dataframe to add to your question? you can imagine that we are not going to type what is in the image! Did you print hue inside your function to check that there is what you expect?

@rehaqds Yes you are right. I added a table for your ref. Thank you.

There are a couple of problems:

In **kwargs there are no "hue", you should use "label". There are also no "var" but you don't use it.
Seaborn calls diagonal_with_line twice per features (once for each of the 2 labels) so the loop needs to be removed. And for the same reason, no need of subset, take the full xdata.

The code below should solve both issues.
g = sns.PairGrid(
    data=df_combined,
    vars=['Temp (°C)', 'SH (g/kg)', 'RH (%)', 'PM2.5 (µg/m³)'],
    hue="Source",
    height=2.5, aspect=1.5,
    diag_sharey=False, despine=False
)

# Map histograms and additional line plots to the diagonal
def diagonal_with_line(xdata, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()  # Get the current axis
    variable = kwargs.get('var')  # Extract the variable name  
    hue = kwargs.get('label')  # Extract the hue parameter if available

    # Plot the histogram
    sns.histplot(x=xdata ,kde=False, **kwargs, ax=ax) 

    ax2 = ax.twinx()

    # Add a line plot for each hue value separately
    # Add a line plot (example: normal fit)
    # Compute a fitted normal distribution PDF as an example

    # for level in xdata[hue].unique(): 
    subset = xdata  # [xdata[hue] == level]
    mu, std = np.mean(subset), np.std(subset)
    x_vals = np.linspace(stats.norm.ppf(0.01, scale=std, loc=mu),
                         stats.norm.ppf(0.99, scale=std, loc=mu), 1000)
    pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x=x_vals, scale=std, loc=mu)
    ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=x_vals, y=pdf, color='red', label="normal fit", ax=ax2)


# Replace the diagonal mapping with the custom function
g.map_diag(diagonal_with_line)#df_combined[])

# Map scatter plots to the off-diagonal plots
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)

